# TypeScript InversifyJS: asynchronous binding

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I'm facing this kind of problem: I'm creating Event Manager with ability to handle several concrete providers, and I'm struggling with dependency injection issue here.

I'm using:
`Typescript@2.0.10`, `node@7.0.0`, `inversify@2.0.1`, `inversify-binding-decorators@2.0.0`

Lets see that in code:

```
const socketIO: SocketIO.Server = io.listen(instance);
kernel.bind<SocketIO.Server>(TYPES.SocketIO).toConstantValue(socketIO);

const eventManager: IEventManager = kernel.get<IEventManager>(TYPES.IEventManager);
eventManager.init(kernel.getAll<IEventManagerProvider>(TYPES.IEventManagerProvider));
console.log(eventManager);
```

And console logs me that event manager is `undefined`, which crashes the whole app. But...
When I disable the `kernel.getAll(...)` from init, then I'm receiving just what I've expected:

```
const eventManager: IEventManager = kernel.get<IEventManager>(TYPES.IEventManager);
eventManager.init([]);
console.log(eventManager);
```

Gives me: `MultipleProvidersEventManager { providers: {} }`. The init method is very simple by itself and contains:

```
@provideSingleton(TYPES.IEventManager)
class MultipleProvidersEventManager { 

    ...

    public init(providers: IEventManagerProvider[]): void {
        forEach(providers, this.registerProvider);
    }

    public registerProvider(provider: IEventManagerProvider): void {
        if (this.providers[provider.type()]) {
            throw new Error('Event Manager provider already registered');
        }
        console.log('Registered ' + provider.type() + ' event manager provider');
        this.providers[provider.type()] = provider;
    }

    ...
}
```

So my problem is that I have to wait with calling the init method until
all required objects are stored properly in InversifyJS container and can be returned. But I don't know how :(. Can someone explain me how should I solve this problem ?

Comment: The file which contains the code is under: https://github.com/sdudziak/js-app-kickstarter/blob/master/src/server/bootstrap.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solve it.

The problem was in totally different place that I was thinking on the beginning.
So... in `MultipleProvidersEventManager` class on `init` method, `forEach` was loosing the context of the caller. Adding `bind` soved the problem..

```
forEach(providers, this.registerProvider.bind(this));
```

... is the anwser.